# Ejabberd - Retrieve archive messages using XmlRpc Client

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

How can I retrieve the archived messages using XmlRpc client. I have enabled the module in the configuration and the archive_msg table has also started storing data.

I went through [this](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) link to retrieve archived messages but I dont understand how to implement these xml snippets. Can someone please help me understand how do I programatically retrieve the archived messages. Is it possible to retrieve them using XmlRpc client, if not then how ?

Answer (score 0):

The protocol in the link tells you how to fetch the archive messages from an xmpp server using an xmpp client. Whereas some servers may provide an API for this, currently the XmlRpc API for ejabberd some provides administration facilities for managing your ejabberd server. The commands are given [here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/). You can also see how to call the API from your app using different languages [here](https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc).